# I ran a command and need to undo it. Can anyone help me with this specific command?

Tags: nvidia

I ran the following in my terminal to fix something for my display on Ubuntu

```
cd /etc/X11
sudo rm xorg.conf
sudo cp xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original xorg.conf
```

But its only made my problem worse, how can i undo this?

Comment: You can't "undo this".

Comment: Did an xorg.conf file actually exist before (i.e. did the `rm` command succeed, or did it error out with a "no such file" message)? Xorg configuration is mostly done dynamically these days iirc

Comment: Normally there is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file and the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` directory would be empty. So, the question is: Was there an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the original configuration file. You can't "undo" this. Restore the original configuration file from your backups.